# Webpack source maps not recognized by Visual Studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, webpack

I am using Visual Studio 2017 for my Typescript project. I tried using Webpack to create a bundle for the source files. The source map produced by Webpack contains the source file urls in this format: "`webpack:///./Main/SomeFile.ts`". This causes Chrome Dev Tools to display webpack as a separate domain in the "**Sources**" tab. And when expanded, I can see the source ts files and successfully set breakpoints. But the problem is that I cannot debug using VS 2017 since the breakpoints I set in the IDE do not work.

As a work-around, I manually replaced all these "`webpack:///.`" parts in the source map file by "../" which now points to the correct paths of the source files relative to the bundle file. And now VS picks up the breakpoints and I can debug inside VS.

My questions are:

1. What is the meaning of "webpack:///" and why is it being produced instead of relative paths?
2. Why doesn't VS 2017 pick up these and work out-of-the-box? And what is the proper solution as opposed to the work-around I tried above?
3. If there is no other solution than the work-around I mentioned, how can I integrate it to the webpack processing pipeline so that I don't have to do it manually every time?

Here are my configs:

***webpack.config.js***

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: "source-map",
    entry: {
        app: './Components/MainComponent/MainComponent.ts'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: __dirname + '/dist'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            { test: /.css$/, use: 'css-loader' },
            { test: /.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader' },
            //{ test: /.ts$/, use: 'awesome-typescript-loader' },
            //{ enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json']
    }
}
```

***tsconfig.json***

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": false,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "allowJs": true,
    "module": "amd",
    "alwaysStrict": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ],
  "compileOnSave": true
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Add this to your webpack.config.js, inside module.exports:

```
devtool: false,
plugins: [
    new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin({
        filename: "[file].map",
        fallbackModuleFilenameTemplate: '[absolute-resource-path]',
        moduleFilenameTemplate: '[absolute-resource-path]'
    })
]
```

This will make breakpoints work in Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: This answer actually helped me answer my question over here! https://stackoverflow.com/q/57332415/5245385

Comment: ReferenceError: webpack is not defined? Oh it needs var webpack = require('webpack');

Comment: SHOCKINGLY THIS JUST WORKS

Comment: `output.devtoolModuleFilenameTemplate: '[absolute-resource-path]'` also does the trick. Works with 'eval-source-map', 'inline-source-map', 'eval-cheap-module-source-map'

Comment: @AlexBuchatski, I tried your suggestion, and while it did work (sort of) I ended up with the "out by one line" issue. ie my breakpoint hit the next line of code. Whereas the answer above seems to work correctly. I'm using Visual Studio 2022.

Comment: The precision of breakpoints depends on type of devtool setting